# AdS/CFT: why is the fifth coordinate in AdS space inversely proportional to an energy scale?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, ads-cft

In several different articles about the AdS/CFT correspondence, it is stated that one can show that the fifth coordinate $z$ on the AdS side, in coordinates such that the AdS metric becomes:  $$ds^2 = \frac{L^2}{z^2}(dt^2-d(x^1)^2 - d(x^2)^2 - d(x^3)^2- dz^2)$$ can be interpreted as an inverse energy scale for the 4D theory on the boundary, unfortunately the root article they link to, i.e. [this review](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9905111), states vacuously that this is clear from looking at the conformal transformations of Poincaré coordinates. Can somebody clarify this a bit further? 
Unfortunately, I'm not extremely familiar with conformal field theory and I'm just trying to get a global heuristic understanding of the correspondance for the moment so that I can understand the ideas behind a phenomenological AdS/QCD model I will working with.

Comment: On a CFT, the energy is given by the dilatation operator that scales the coordinates - $x^\mu \to \lambda x^\mu$. The isometry of AdS that acts as a dilation on the boundary is one in which $z \to \lambda z$. This is the sense in which $z$ is the inverse energy scale.

Comment: @Prahar Is this statement coordinate independent, i.e., what the global coordinates?

Answer (score 3):

There are various ways of arguing that $z$ should be an inverse energy scale, none of them to my knowledge very precise.  In fact, it's not clear to me that it is possible to make a precise relationship between $z$ and energy scale.

That said, perhaps the simplest way of arguing for the relationship is to note that for massive particles, AdS is like a well: the larger $z$, the deeper the particle is in the well and the less potential energy it has.

Comment: A paper which has come out since this answer was posted might help: https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.08516

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the comment of Prahar:

CFT is invariant under scaling $x^\mu \to \alpha x^\mu$. Length scale is inverse in energy thus energy scales as $E \to E/\alpha$.

Now let's see the metric in Poincare coordinate
$$ dS^2=\frac{\ell^2}{z^2}(\eta_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu +dz^2 ).$$

Scale transformation in CFT side translates to diffeomorphism invariance in gravity side with $x^\mu \to \alpha x^\mu$ and $z \to \alpha z$. Thus $z \sim E^{-1}$. This has physical implication. UV divergences in CFT thus implies IR divergences in gravitational theories if integrated over the holographic $z$ direction.